# pjs sketches and html canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing.js

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing when I stick a pjs sketch to an html canvas in the following way.

```
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas> 
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js">
</script>

<script>
var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
with (processingInstance) {     
size(800, 400);      
frameRate(30);

draw = function() {
  background(235, 245, 255);
};

}};
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");     
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
</script>
```

When I began learning this stuff, I was eager to add my animations to an html doc. I learned the above way pretty much how I imagine a hamster can learn to push a button and receive a pellet; that is, I don't understand the mechanism well, but the result is positive.

Here is the above example in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/h1Lb91ux/

Here is my attempt at making sense of this.

The following code is defining a function called sketchProc.

```
var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
with (processingInstance) {     
size(800, 400);      
frameRate(30);

draw = function() {
  background(235, 245, 255);
};

}};
```

This doesn't return anything because we're just defining sketchProc, not calling it. It's argument is processingInstance, which is being defined as a local variable just like if I did:

```
var functionX = function(x) {
  return x;
};
```

But I do not understand the with statement. I know of with statements from excel-vba, which can be used to attach multiple methods to an object without having to repeatedly type out the object name. Is this the same?

The following statement makes perfect sense.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
```

But this next one is a source of confusion:

```
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
```

To me, this looks like we're making a single instance or object from an object constructor function (in javascript) or a class (in processing), which takes 2 arguments: canvas and sketchproc. We're calling this specific instance processingInstance, which confusingly is the same name as the local variable used in the function sketchProc.

I hope this is not too rambling.

Comment: Yeah I think the "var processingInstance" could be called something else as its just the name of the new processing instance.

Comment: Aha. Here is another fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnuq6apg/
This has 2 different canvas tags each with a different instance of the sketch attached. So this, as far as I'm concerned, confirms that "var processingInstance" is just an instance. So far so good.

Comment: Cool. Your understanding of the rest of it seems correct. Yeah that "with" keyword is a funky thing. A quick google should find some blog posts which explain it.

Comment: But what is odd is that, when sketchProc is defined to take an argument, processingInstance. Yet, when I do, "var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);" sketchProc isn't being fed an argument. So that is confusing too. I feel like I'm starting to get it, but there are elements which still elude me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code is defining a function called sketchProc.
>
> ```
> var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
> with (processingInstance) {     
> size(800, 400);      
> frameRate(30);
>
> draw = function() {
>   background(235, 245, 255);
> };
>
> }};
> ```

It's defining a **function object** that itself contains functions like `draw()`. You can read more about function objects [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-objects), but basically this is just an instance that contains functions that Processing can call.

> But I do not understand the with statement.

Try googling something like "javascript with" for a ton of results, including [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). But my understanding is that it's a shortcut to avoid having to call `processingInstance.` before everything. You can try removing the `with` statement and putting `processingInstance.` before any Processing function to see the alternative. The `with` is optional, but makes you code slightly shorter. I personally don't like the use of `with` here, but that's just me.

> But this next one is a source of confusion:
>
> ```
> var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
> ```
>
> To me, this looks like we're making a single instance or object from
>   an object constructor function (in javascript) or a class (in
>   processing), which takes 2 arguments: canvas and sketchproc. We're
>   calling this specific instance processingInstance, which confusingly
>   is the same name as the local variable used in the function
>   sketchProc.

Your understanding sounds about right. Creating an instance of `Processing` is what kicks off all of the Processing magic, calling the `setup()` function and the `draw()` function for you automatically. You can also rename the variable if it confuses you.

Taking a step back, this code uses Processing.js's **instance mode**, which is why you have all this extra code that you don't really understand. I would recommend you start with the more basic global mode, which would allow your code to look like this:

```
<script type="application/processing">
function setup(){
  size(800, 400);      
  frameRate(30);
}

function draw() {
  background(235, 245, 255);
};
</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
```

I'm also curious why you're using Processing.js. If you're coming from a JavaScript background, you might have more luck with [P5.js](https://p5js.org/) instead.

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand this code more clearly and I'll spend the weekend fiddling with it. I view the question kind of like if I was a carpenter and I didn't understand how a fancy drill worked, but was still able to build the tables and chairs I wanted. And my choice of processing.js is borne partly of inexperience. It's the only library I've played around with. In that last piece of code you wrote, in global mode, shouldn't setup() and draw() be voids? Or is that different? I accept your answer because it gives me what I need to figure out the rest myself, which I'm keen to do.

Comment: @Jozurcrunch Processing.js is a little weird in that it can take Processing (Java) code and convert it to Processing.js (JavaScript) code, or you can just write JavaScript code directly. So you could write Java code by declaring the functions in Java's style with a `void` return type, or you could write JavaScript code by declaring the functions in JavaScript's style, which is what I did here because the code in your question was using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As far as the with statement is concerned, you are right. Here is the same fiddle as above but rewritten without the with statement: https://jsfiddle.net/ko86zn8s/